# Any limitation about mapping devices to GCM topics?

Tags: google-cloud-messaging

Because GCM's site changed dynamically, I could not find out limitation information about current GCM.
SO provides some information, but most of these sources are out-of-date.
What is the current limitation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GCM now offers [unlimited subscriptions per app](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/topic-messaging) as opposed to previous 1Million limitation.